# Javascript Replace doesn't work because of Escape Sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace every '\n' in a var with a `<br>` tag but the code I tried doesn't work. Here's my example and code:

Example:

> Hello there \n Are you online? \n What do you mean?

Should become:

> `Hello there <br> Are you online? <br> What do you mean?`

Code:

```
var text = 'Hello there \n Are you online? \n What do you mean?';
var find = '\n';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');

re = text .replace(re, '<br>');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output do you see? it works as you expect in Chrome 46.

Comment: Works fine in Safari 9 and latest Fx too.

Comment: I see - you are assigning the output to `re`. You probably mean to use another variable. Did you mean `text = text.replace...` ?

Comment: @joews it's weird that he does that but it doesn't break his example code.

Comment: Check this out. What is wrong with it? https://jsfiddle.net/pmmquhL9/4/ @Touffy

Comment: why so many down votes? It's a simple question and it's well defined.

Comment: You have accepted an answer that just repeats **the exact same code** you have in the question – so it should be obvious that you didn't post your *actual* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var text = 'Hello there \n Are you online? \n What do you mean?';
var find = '\n';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');

re = text.replace(re, '<br>');
document.write(re);
```

Works fine

Answer (score 0):

in your fiddle you wrote :

```
 document.findElementById
```

instead of

```
 document.getElementById
```

I think it is one of things that should solve your issue !

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmmquhL9/15/)

In your fiddle (which you did not post in your original question) there are several issues addressed already in the comments.  But the crux of your problem -- that would have helped us help you faster -- is that you're pulling a string with "\n" from an innerHTML property.  Those are not newline characters, because if you're seeing a literal "\n" instead of a newline, it means it has been escaped.  Therefore, you need to use "\\n" in your regular expression, not "\n".  Use the devtool consoles in modern browsers to inspect your variables and catch errors.

Code:

```
var el = document.getElementById("ado")
var text = document.getElementById("ado").innerHTML;

text = text.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>');

el.innerHTML = text
```